# Get cursor position, relative to a scaled image which is placed in the middle of the screen

Tags: java, swing, math, graphics

I have a swing GUI app, which is basically an image editor but I have issues when implementing zooming functionality and finding the position of the mouse/cursor relative to the image.

I have a **canvas** (JPanel) and an **image** (BufferedImage).

The image is drawn in such a way, so that the image appears centered on the canvas, the math for getting the mouse position relative to the image was quite simple, simply subtract the space between the image "origin" and the canvas origin:

[image: fig1]

However, what happens when the "image" is scaled, drawn on a smaller portion of the canvas? Smaller like this, for example:

[image: Scaled image, drawn smaller.]

How would I get the position of the mouse, relative the **canvas** and make it relative to the **image** inside the canvas instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: everything is very simple (two three methods from SwingUtilities), it could be little bit complicated in the case that container is inside JScrollPane (one code line more over)

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnale, compilable without external resources (e.g. image)